# EFS persistent volume claim failed

Tags: nginx, amazon-efs

I'm trying deploy nginx app, with volume mounts in EFS file system. after deploying manifest yaml file my pod ins pending state at the same time i verified pv/pc and it got bounded already here the logs.

Here the yam file pvc and deployment yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: nginx
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: nginx
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers: 
        - image: "nginx:latest"
          name: nginx
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 80
              name: nginx
         
          volumeMounts: 
            - mountPath: "/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC"
              name: nginx-localtime
            - mountPath: "/var/log/nginx/"
              name: nginx-log
            - mountPath: "/var/log/cache/"
              name: nginx-cache
         
      volumes: 
        - name: nginx-localtime
          persistentVolumeClaim: 
            claimName: nginx-localtime
        - name: nginx-log
          persistentVolumeClaim: 
            claimName: nginx-log
        - name: nginx-cache
          persistentVolumeClaim: 
            claimName: nginx-cache
```

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-localtime
spec:
  storageClassName: efs
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Mi
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-log
spec:
  storageClassName: efs
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Mi
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-cache
spec:
  storageClassName: efs
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Mi
```

```
[root@ip-10-1-2-3 nginx]# kubectl get pvc
NAME              STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
nginx-cache       Bound    pvc-d35df958-1288-4028-bf38-d880ec09824f   10Mi       RWX            efs            49s
nginx-localtime   Bound    pvc-ec5b15c0-a9d1-468a-989c-48a18332bbbb   10Mi       RWX            efs            49s
nginx-log         Bound    pvc-c84f1a46-ceba-4180-a2ce-95e19d3d9614   10Mi       RWX            efs            49s

[root@ip-10-1-2-3 nginx]# kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                     STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-c84f1a46-ceba-4180-a2ce-95e19d3d9614   10Mi       RWX            Delete           Bound    default/nginx-log         efs                     54s
pvc-d35df958-1288-4028-bf38-d880ec09824f   10Mi       RWX            Delete           Bound    default/nginx-cache       efs                     53s
pvc-ec5b15c0-a9d1-468a-989c-48a18332bbbb   10Mi       RWX            Delete           Bound    default/nginx-localtime   efs                     54s

Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  36s (x2 over 36s)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 persistentvolumeclaim "nginx-localtime" not found.
  Normal   Scheduled         34s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx-5c9777db9b-mjc75 to ip-10-1-2-3.eu-central-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulled            31s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx:latest" in 1.726030163s
  Normal   Pulled            29s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx:latest" in 1.898012878s
  Normal   Pulling           15s (x3 over 33s)  kubelet            Pulling image "nginx:latest"
  Normal   Created           13s (x3 over 31s)  kubelet            Created container nginx
  Normal   Started           13s (x3 over 31s)  kubelet            Started container nginx
  Normal   Pulled            13s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx:latest" in 1.580634471s
  Warning  BackOff           12s (x3 over 27s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

i'm not able to understand after bounding pvc still my nginx pod is not coming up could you please some one help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PV and PVC have one-to-one mapping. That is only one PVC can be bounded with one PV. First check that you have 3 PV for the 3 PVCs you are trying to bound.

```
kubectl get pv
```

Also note that once you have deleted a PVC its corresponding PV is not available for the bounding, as one might expect. In my experience you have to create a new PV and PVC.
Also you can mention the name of PV to bound to in your PVC yaml like below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: <your-pvc-name>
spec:
  volumeName: <your-pv-name>
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Comment: If i use above format my PVC in pending state and there is no pv using kubectl get pv command

Comment: do you need my deployment yam file as well?

Comment: I think you need to delete these pv and pvcs and create new pv and pvcs. Also would be helpful if you could share the pod logs

Comment: Yes Agrawal i tried its not working, i deploy many pod all are working fine except nginx.
i will update the deployment file as well wait

Comment: @Agrawal could you please help me i updated deployment file

Comment: In your volumeMounts you have used "/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC", I am not sure if it is correct. Never used -> in path, I guess it should be only "/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC". You can comment this from mounts and volume and try

Comment: if something issue means why my pv and pvc  got bounded ? see my above logs from kubectl

Comment: Yup pv and pvcs are bounding properly. Issue in deployment file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233776/discussion-between-gowmi-and-rahul-agrawal).

Comment: Now i completely remove nginx localtime from deployment and pvc yaml file now error moved to another level  0/2 nodes are available: 2 persistentvolumeclaim "nginx-log" not found.